# Setting line start position does not work when using double foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, draw

I am drawing a nice diagram with Tikz. The following works perfectly:

```
\foreach \m [
evaluate=\m as \nstart using ((\m - 1) * 4) + 1,
evaluate=\m as \nstep using ((\m - 1) * 4) + 2,
evaluate=\m as \nend using ((\m - 1)* 4) + 5] in {1,2,...,5}
\foreach \i in {\nstart,\nstep,...,\nend}

\draw (input-\i) -- (hidden-1-\m);
```

Now, I want the line to start at the top if `input-\i`, so I use:

```
\draw (input-\i.north) -- (hidden-1-\m);
```

However, this terminates with ``` Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator ``n' or ``no' (in '0.north'). \draw (input-\i.north) -- (hidden-1-\m); ```.

How could I fix this error or work around it?

Here is a minimal example which reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\tikzset{%
    tdnn neuron/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        minimum height=0.5cm,
        minimum width=0.1cm 
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]
    % Layers
    \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2,...,21}
    \node [tdnn neuron] (input-\m) at (0-\y*0.25,0) {};

    \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2,...,5}
    \node [tdnn neuron] (hidden-1-\m) at (0-\y*1 + 0.25,1) {};

    \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1}
    \node [tdnn neuron] (classify-\m) at (0-\y*0.25 - 10 * 0.25,2) {};

    %Edges
    \foreach \m [
    evaluate=\m as \nstart using ((\m - 1) * 4) + 1,
    evaluate=\m as \nstep using ((\m - 1) * 4) + 2,
    evaluate=\m as \nend using ((\m - 1)* 4) + 5] in {1,2,...,5}
    \foreach \i in {\nstart,\nstep,...,\nend}
    \draw (input-\i.north) -- (hidden-1-\m); % Error happens here. 


    \foreach \m in {1,2,...,5}
    \draw (hidden-1-\m) -- (classify-1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I have a hard time believing that this error message comes from the line you're showing. There is no `(hidden-1-\m)` in it.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I added a minimal example. That reproduces the error. Furthermore, you were right, it only happens in nested for-each loops. The snipped I posted initally was too minimal. :)

Comment: Your `\i` is a decimal number, while your coordinate needs an integer in its name

Comment: @samcarter - Why does it stop working as soon as I add `.north` and how could I solve this problem?

Comment: @Emiswelt It stops working because `input-1.0.north` does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the integer part in the coordinate name, you could use `\pgfmathparse{int(\i)}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\tikzset{%
    tdnn neuron/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        minimum height=0.5cm,
        minimum width=0.1cm 
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]
    % Layers
    \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2,...,21}
    \node [tdnn neuron] (input-\m) at (0-\y*0.25,0) {};

    \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2,...,5}
    \node [tdnn neuron] (hidden-1-\m) at (0-\y*1 + 0.25,1) {};

    \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1}
    \node [tdnn neuron] (classify-\m) at (0-\y*0.25 - 10 * 0.25,2) {};

    %Edges
    \foreach \m [
    evaluate=\m as \nstart using ((\m - 1) * 4) + 1,
    evaluate=\m as \nstep using ((\m - 1) * 4) + 2,
    evaluate=\m as \nend using ((\m - 1)* 4) + 5] in {1,2,...,5}
    \foreach \i in {\nstart,\nstep,...,\nend}{
    \pgfmathparse{int(\i)}
    \draw (input-\pgfmathresult.north) -- (hidden-1-\m); % Error happens here. 
        }

    \foreach \m in {1,2,...,5}{
        \draw (hidden-1-\m) -- (classify-1);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of using `\pgfmathparse{int(\i)}` over using `int(...)` in the evaluate statement?

Comment: @Emiswelt I don't know, it probably depends if you use the variables also for something else - I just posted it as an alternative way.

Answer (score 2):

According to @samcarter's comment, the answer:

My `evaluate` expression yields a decimal number. Hence, Tikz looks for `input-1.0` and `input-1.0.north`, respective. The first case works, the second does not.

The solution is casting the expression to integer:

```
\foreach \m [
evaluate=\m as \nstart using int(((\m - 1) * 4) + 1),
evaluate=\m as \nstep using int(((\m - 1) * 4) + 2),
evaluate=\m as \nend using int(((\m - 1)* 4) + 5)] in {1,2,...,5}
\foreach \i in {\nstart,\nstep,...,\nend}
\draw (input-\i.north) -- (hidden-1-\m);
```